# Creating shortcuts in mysql client for requests such as `show tables;` or `show databases;`

Tags: mysql

I often use the mysql client in text mode (`mysql`).
And some requests are so frequent I'd like to shorten them.

Ideally I would like to use:

```
tables;     For "show tables;"
dbs;        For "show databases;"
```

Is this possible without recompiling the client?

Comment: Looks like an existing feature request: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26229